# How to Re-arrange proxy address and mail via powershell

Tags: email, powershell

I just need to be able to trim that down to just the SMTP. Right now I get a list of all proxy addresses

```
Get-ADUser -filter 'Enabled -eq "True"'  -Properties proxyaddresses,mail | Where {$_.proxyAddresses -like "SMTP*"} | select-object mail,@{n='SMTPproxyaddresses';e={($_.proxyaddresses | ? {$_ -match '^smtp'})-join'; '}} | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation C:\Export\allusers4.csv
```

Output at this time :

```
mail                    SMTPproxyaddresses
user1@contoso.com       SMTP:userproxy@contoso.com;SMTP:user.test@contoso.com
                        SMTP:testproxy@contoso.com
user2@contoso.com       smtp:user2@exchn.contoso.com;SMTP:user2proxy@contoso.com
user3@contoso.com       SMTP:user3proxy@contoso.com
```

I want to get an output like below. I just need to be able to trim that down to just the SMTP

```
SMTPproxyaddresses
userproxy@contoso.com
testproxy@contoso.com
user2proxy@contoso.com
user3proxy@contoso.com
```

Comment: Just that column, nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use -cmatch for the match to be case sensitive. As for dropping the first column, just exclude it from your select.

I believe something like this should do the trick...

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq "True"' -Properties proxyaddresses | 
where { $_.proxyAddresses -like "SMTP*" } | 
select-object @{ n='SMTPproxyaddresses';e={ ($_.proxyaddresses | where { $_ -cmatch '^SMTP'})-join'; ' -replace 'SMTP:'} } | 
Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation C:\Export\allusers4.csv
```